# Managing deployment of complex set of wasm contracts

Tags: smart-contract, wasm

We need to deploy a set of several smart contracts, x-compiled from Solidity to wasm, and maintain that deployment (deploy new contract instances and migrate to them once in a while).

So what we ideally would like to use is sort-of a `hardhat-deploy`, but for Substrate. **We are wondering how other dotsama ecosystem protocols do it.**

`swanky` is a good start, but like one level too low. You still need sort-of a runner that checks what contracts have been deployed yet, which ones should be redeployed and then run deployment scripts that invoke swanky.

Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Swanky dev here. Feel free to add a suggestion on GH with the use case description. We have been thinking in that direction with next iteration planning, and a real-world use case would be a great help. https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-cli/issues

Comment: Thank you, @codespool! I just created an issue in your repo: https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-cli/issues/144

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Typechain allows writing some not hard scripts for deploying smart contracts, but I'm not sure that that's the thing you are searching for. Anyway, you can check it here: https://github.com/Brushfam/typechain-polkadot

Comment: Thanks! Not really what we are looking for, though. swanky is essentially already one level too low-level and typechain is more or less a level below swanky even.

The question is not so much about feasibility of complex deployments, but rather how to do it in a brief, convenient manner without re-inventing the wheel ;)

Answer (score 2):

At `useInkathon` (https://github.com/scio-labs/use-inkathon) I offer a pretty straightforward `deployContract` script, together with some additional helpers defined in inkathon.xyz this results in super simple deploy scripts (example: https://github.com/scio-labs/inkathon/blob/main/packages/contracts/scripts/deploy.ts). Here at AZERO Domains we deploy a set of several dependant, rather complex contracts in a few lines only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tool that we need in the ecosystem. You must currently do this via your own scripts + PolkadotJS, or via ContractsUI.

If you or someone would like to build something like hardhat-deploy there are grants available through [use.ink/ubator/](https://use.ink/ubator/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, the best way currently would be to script something that under the hood uses `cargo-contract` or `polkadot-js/api`.

I know this is far from ideal and we actively want to help get to a better solution. Please, if you have any requirements in `cargo-contract` that would ease this for you, just create an issue in https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues.

We will soon merge a PR for `cargo contract info`, which will enable you to query the state of a contract on-chain.